# MVC: why the separation of model, view, and controller?

Tags: model-view-controller

Other than the “philosophical” aspects of it, is it a bad idea to have my controller also be my model?

It seems to save some programming time. I don’t have to create logic between the controller and the model, since it’s the same thing. And I can directly interact with the view.

What’s the point of separating the M and the C? Is modularity — that is, the ability to swap one model and controller set for another — the only reason to separate them? It seems to me that “swapping” modules out happens a lot less than (for example) having to update both the model and the controller because something in the model is changing.

---

It seems odd that a simple calculator, according to the MVC concept, should have both a controller and a view for its settings (like default settings, or something).  I know this is a simple example, but it seems to apply to all cases (except maybe frameworks).

Comment: I suggest you remove all the tags other than 'mvc', they are not relevant to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary reason is for reusability of code. If you’re only ever going to write one program in your professional life, then perhaps it doesn’t matter. If you plan to make a career of it, having reusable pieces is valuable. Well-designed model, controller and view classes are very easy to drop into other programs. I do this all the time.

Consider `UITableViewController`, which is a Controller. Now imagine if it were designed exclusively to handle music tracks (the Model), and you needed to create a completely different table-management class when you wanted to handle something else. Avoiding this nightmare is why MVC is heavily used in Cocoa.

There are other ways to split things up. Some languages subclass heavily rather than delegating. But in Cocoa, the primary means of splitting up programs is MVC, and it works very well.

**EDIT:** Just some more reasons from the world of developing commercial apps.

- Memory handling is much easier in MVC. You can hold on to your model objects and throw away your view objects (and many of your controller objects) when they go offscreen.
- It’s easier to serialize model objects that aren’t wrapped up with controllers and views, and it’s much easier to display the same data in multiple ways. Even in a “simple” text editor, you may want to be able to do split-screen, or have multiple windows showing the same document. In MVC that’s very easy.

If you need no flexibility now or in the future, you don’t need much architecture. But most real projects aren’t so simple. MVC grew out of Xerox’s experience with writing large programs and the difficulties encountered when everything was thrown together.

---

**EDIT 2:** I was looking at your earlier edit: “It seems odd that a simple calculator, according to the MVC concept, should have both a controller and a view for its settings (like default settings, or something).”

This is exactly the reason for MVC. It would seem crazy to have to re-code all of the things required for saving user settings specially for a Calculator app. You’d want a generic “please save these user settings” that was completely separate from the UI and that you could reuse. On OS X it’s called `NSUserDefaults`, and the `Calculator` app stores its configuration in exactly this way.

Comment: UITableViewController is a part of a framework.  I understand why it's a good idea for frameworks to use MVC.  But why should individual projects use MVC?

Comment: For the same reason frameworks do. So you can reuse the code, and so you can keep the code focused on its part of the problem, making refactoring easier. Again, if you will never write another program in your life, and don't plan to maintain this one for very long, then throwing everything together might be fine. But a collection of reusable code and projects that are easy to refactor are important parts of any long-term professional developer's toolkit.

Comment: But with that logic, the code base explodes.  I'd have to have a view for the editor.  Then I'd have to have a controller for the editor.  Then I'd have to have a controlled for the model (to verify it's written correctly, validated, etc).  And then glue to tue the controller with the model.

Comment: On Mac, take a look at `/Developer/Examples/TextEdit` to see how a simple text editor is broken down in MVC. This is the actual source code to the `TextEdit` app that comes with the OS. I don't think it's an unreasonable number of classes. I'd count them as 3 models, 7 controllers and 3 views. Four of the controllers are UI controllers, and three are model controllers. Note that much of it is written in Objective C 1.0, which is why most of the accessors are written by hand. But it's a good example.

Comment: @Rob based on your last comment : what's the difference bw `UI controller` vs `model controller` ?

Comment: A model controller manages model objects. By "UI controller" I just mean "things that manage view objects" while trying to avoid the specific term "view controller." `UIViewController` is the most common type in iOS, but on Mac it is somewhat common to have UI controller objects that are not `NSViewController` or `NSWindowController`. (`NSViewController` is not nearly as useful a class as `UIViewController`.)

Answer (score 3):

MVC is a standard pattern that is well understood in the development community, and for good reasons.  The separation really makes things easy to read, easy to troubleshoot, easy to find, and easy to test, as individual components, each with its own area of responsibility.

Do you have to use it? of course not.  But keeping the parts separate is generally considered a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

The controller knows how to link a specific view to your model. The separation of model and controller, apart from improving documentation and maintainability, has the immediate benefit of allowing multiple views to display the same information from the model without adding any complexity to either.

That applies not just to multiple views in the same application, but also to the multiple variations in views you'll have across multiple versions of your application. Your model is insulated and logically clean.

Combining model and controller is a classic false economy in my opinion. It may feel like it saves a few minutes, but it costs significantly as an application develops and grows.

Answer (score 1):

If it works for you then it works. Period.  The reason for separation of Models, Views, and Controllers revolves around the idea that most development for enterprise applications is done by a team of developers.

Imagine 10 developers trying to work on your controller.  But all they want to do is add something to the model.  Now your Controller broke?  What did they do?

Answer (score 1):

The Models are usually separate components which can be re-used between Controllers. If you are **absolutely** certain you won't be re-using Models in multiple Controller, I don't really see a problem with blending these concerns.

I guess one could argue why even use MVC design if you are planning on deviating. Maybe there is a more suitable pattern to follow for your situation. Can you give us an example of something you've done where the Controller is the Model? It would help us understand what you are trying to do better.

Comment: Even for a basic text editor, it doesn't make sense to separate the M and C.  Why shouldn't the editor's internal data contain the actual document?

Comment: Even in a "simple" text editor, you may want multiple windows showing the same text file, or multiple views in the same window showing different parts. That's hard if you mix; easy if you separate.

Answer (score 0):

MVC is all about management (separation of data, representation and business logic). So it's like this: if you run a small company, having a MS-sized management would be a real drag. But if you are a giant corporation, not having big middle management is impossible.

Honestly, in most of my college progamming assignments, I combined the models and controllers, because I didn't see the need for the separation. But working on big projects? The deficiency would be pretty obvious if you try to not separate. Just do what you feel right.

Answer (score 0):

The model depends on neither the view nor the controller. This is one the key benefits of the separation. This separation allows the model to be built and tested independent of the visual presentation.