# How do you define a global IBOutlet variable in iOS5?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, global-variables, iboutlet

The reason why I need a global IBOutlet variable is because, I don't want to lose data after you switch view back. for example, I have an `IBOutlet` and `UIlabel` and set its text.

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView; 
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *inputText; 
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *warnningLabel;
```

After I switch back from the other view, UILabel will be set to nil, which I don't want it happen. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

save the value using NSUserDefaults (or declare a global NSString variable) on viewDidDisappear and set UILabel.text on viewDidAppear

Answer (score 3):

Your question suggests that you're storing data inside of the view. That means you've violated MVC (Model-View-Controller), which is the source of your problem. The correct solution is to move your data out of the view and view controller, and put it into separate model objects. Then you don't care when you're on the screen or off. As Andrei G notes, you will re-load the data from the model in `viewWillAppear:`.

Some previous discussions on this topic:

- [Organizing iOS project for MVC design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227904/organizing-ios-project-for-mvc-design-pattern/5228317#5228317)
- [MVC: passing model pointer to a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475223/mvc-passing-model-pointer-to-a-view/9475654#9475654)
- [Cocoa MVC: where is application work logic intended to be placed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386614/cocoa-mvc-where-is-application-work-logic-intended-to-be-placed/8386787#8386787)
- [MVC: why the separation of model, view, and controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045093/separation-of-model-view-controller/7045208#7045208)
- [GCD implementation on a UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110884/gcd-implementation-on-a-uitableview/10111155#10111155)